# set the schema while writing the parquet file using SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

When I write a Spark DataFrame as parquet file into the azure data lake and read that back into Databricks, I don't always get the variables with the correct schema. There seems to be many questions on this using pyspark, java, and others, but I am finding it difficult to convert that to SparkR code.

How can I set the schema while writing the parquet file using SparkR?

```
library(SparkR); library(magrittr)

mtcars %>% 
as.DataFrame() %>%
SparkR::coalesce(1L) %>% 
write.df("...azure data lake store path", source = "parquet", mode = "overwrite", header = "true")
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are looking for. Spark doesn't really have concept of "schema while writing".

Comment: Ok. How should I set the variable type say date for a date variable in the Parquet file? Do I need to read and change the variable type everytime I use the Parquet file?

Comment: All types of the Parquet output are determined by the schema of the written DataFrame - if  schema varies it likely means that the process that migrates data to Parquet is faulty (for example depends on schema inference).

Comment: Sorry, I am little new to this! What is the meaning of 'process that migrates data to Parquet is faulty (for example depends on schema inference)'. I used write.df with source as parquet to write SparkDataFrame to parquet.

Comment: Note that `header` option is meaningless for Parquet format; the schema definition is always bundled within each file at write time.The trick is that by default, when reading back a bunch of Parquet files, Spark picks _one_ at random to get the schema for _all_ -- if another file has an extra column it will be ignored. You can force Spark to do "schema merging" across all input files, by setting a specific property, with some performance penalty.

Comment: R is an alien thing to me, but I understand you build a native R "table" and then convert it to a Spark dataframe... with _implicit_ conversion of R types to Java types (wrapped within Spark/Scala objects). Then later you have _implicit_ conversion back to R types. You can't expect Spark to automagically find exact conversion rules for R types that probably don't have direct equivalents in Java...

Comment: In theory: display the schema of the original dataframe before writing the data, and watch out for different types in different cases _(i.e. a single rogue numeric value may trigger a fallback to String)_ ; design explicit Spark conversion rules that fit all cases ; change your script to create a 2nd dataframe from the original one, adding converted cols then removing the original cols ; and write that 2nd dataframe to disk _(Spark will build only the final DF at the time of writing, from the sum of implicit/explicit conversions, and ignore the "temp" one)_

Comment: Thank you for the detailed responses! I am not sure I followed everything, but can you provide any sample code to deal with the Schema.